# rspec: How to capture exit from a new thread?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, rspec

So, I am able to capture `exit` in rspec this way:

`expect { exit }.to raise_error(SystemExit)`

But, if the `exit` was called inside a new thread, the whole rspec run exits:

`expect { Thread.new { exit } }.to raise_error(SystemExit)`

Is there a way to capture `exit` from a new thread gracefully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but you can call join on that newly created thread. That seems to work for me.

```
expect { Thread.new { exit }.join }.to raise_error(SystemExit)
```